# Why does this closure not work when used in a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to understand why this closure doesn't work as expected when used from a React component.

```
// state.ts
const state = { things: [] };

export function setThings(newThings: number[]) {
  state.things = newThings;
}
```

```
// App.tsx
import { setThings } from "./state";

function App() {
  const setThingsToArray = () => setThings([0, 1, 2]);
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={setThingsToArray}>Set things</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When `setThings` is called from non-React code it works as expected. It changes the `things` property of `state`.

However when I try to call it from a React component, as in App.tsx, it doesn't work at all. Debugging shows that when `setThings` is called from inside `App`, it thinks that `state.things` is an empty array `[]`, the value it was initialised to, even though `state.things` already contains lots of items.

This seems to imply that React is somehow using a copied version of `setThings` with a copied version of `state`. How is this possible? Shouldn't it work as a simple closure and reference the real `state`?

---

I don't want to use React state management like Hooks or Redux because I want high performance for the changes in the array, as this is powering a canvas app with lots of particles and redraws per second. So I don't want to have to go through the entire React lifecycle if I don't need the React components to display the data.

**EDIT:** I made a mistake when writing up my component code for this question ‍♂️. I fixed it now. The problem in my question is still happening.

**EDIT 2:**

Because @KevinB asked for proof that calling `setThings` elsewhere is correctly updating my array: https://youtu.be/Gp77NtqNQzo

Every "planet" in the canvas is represented by one item in the array. Coordinates and acceleration of every planet changes on every frame. When planets collide `setThings` is called with the changed array of planets. This needs to happen because multiple planets can "crash" into each other and combine into one, thus resulting in a `state.things` array with 2 items removed and 1 new item added.

Clicking the button calls `setThings` with an array containing only a single planet object. But as you can see it does nothing.

Comment: Not sure why you don't have the values 0,1,2, but you're shadowing the setThings function by naming the variable the same. That means that onClick won't call the function, but will instead try to call the return value from the initial call to that function.

Comment: Does it still not work?

Comment: @CarlosSá the current code is what my real code is like. My previous code was a mistake I made when summarising my code for the question.

Comment: Where are you "using" the state? As far as my understanding goes in TS compiling you may only be able to access it inside the module where you import it

Comment: I import `state` into `main.ts` where it is used to draw on a canvas. This calls a function from a third file `functions.ts` which in turn imports `setThings` and calls it successfully. This shows that `functions.ts` uses the actual `state` object and doesn't just copy it locally, which you're suggesting is what's happening in `App.tsx`.

Comment: How exactly are you confirming that it isn't updating the object you expect it to? I don't see you ever using it. I think you might be misunderstanding how react's rendering works.

Comment: @KevinB in my actual code I have a `main.ts` file that renders something in a canvas for each item in the array on every frame. Pressing the button should change the array and therefore change what's drawn on the canvas. This doesn't happen. Plus, when putting a breakpoint inside `setThings` I can see that it thinks `state.nodes` is an empty array, even though the canvas is drawing lots of items. When I call `setThings` from outside `App` the debugger correctly shows that `state.nodes` contains a bunch of items.

Comment: yeah, that's not how react works. Changing some random array that a component relies on isn't going to cause react to render the change unless you somehow tell react that a change has occured, such as through setState or using something like mobx or redux.

Comment: Can you provide an example in codesandbox ?

Comment: @KevinB I explicitly say in my question that I am not expecting a rerender from React. I am not displaying any data inside React. I merely expect the button to call the function with the closure referencing the real `state` object.

Comment: @Aron Again, how are you confirming that that isn't happening? You just stated that doing so should cause a canvas to change. That's not gonna happen automagically.

Comment: I agree with @Kevin but if you don't want the full dependency of redux then maybe build a small observer/subscriber class

Comment: @KevinB again, because of the debugger and the canvas - which I can see because the canvas rerenders every frame, 60 times a second.

Comment: @CarlosSá again, I am not looking for a React rerender. I just want the component to call the function with the correct closure reference.

Comment: Provide a screenshot if you must, but just saying "because" isn't gonna work.

Comment: @KevinB I posted a link that illustrates the problem and how I know `setThings` works correctly when called outside of React.

Comment: I mean... that video doesn't show anything but you clicking a button and it not doing anything. that's... not all that useful to debugging this problem. I need to see how you are using this. It is *far* more likely that you are mis-understanding what you are seeing than for a closure to all of a sudden not be a closure because you used it in react.

Comment: More importantly, how are you using `state` from setThings? how does that get to your canvas? How does your canvas get informed that the value has changed?

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning anything from the `setThings` in state.ts

Yet you are assigning it to a `const setThings` in App.tsx

And on the `<button onClick={setThings}>` the `setThings` you are referencing is the `undefined` return from the call you make.

Try assigning an actual function to the `<button>` like this:

```
// App.tsx
import { setThings } from "./state";

function App() {
  const setThingsClickHandler = () => {
     setThings([0, 1, 2]);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={setThingsClickHandler}>Set things</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: My bad @Carlos. I made a mistake in summarising my code. I fixed it now. The problem is still happening as it was before. Your solution is exactly what I've currently got. The closure is still not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that because I was importing `main.ts` and `App.tsx` from my HTML file directly via two separate `<script>` tags, Parcel created two entirely separate bundles for them, which means that there was a separate `state` object in each bundle.

This is why updating one would not affect the other.